# Jmeter Construct Parameter Value based on DataSet

Tags: jmeter, preprocessor, jsr223

In JMeter, I want to construct the request parameter value from a dataset file based on the PropertyCount.

**Dataset**

```
PropertyCount   propertyid1 propertyid2 propertyid3
2               13029526    15763743        
3               13029526    15763743    12345645    
2               13029526    15763743
```

**Request Input Parameter**

"values":["13029526","15763743"]

"values":[${outputString}]

**PreProcessor Script**

With the  the below preprocessor script, I am getting the following output but looking to get the values as in Request Input Parameter, with quotes.

2021-08-29 22:15:04,706 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: Required output: 13029526,15763743,
2021-08-29 22:15:04,785 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: Required output: 13029526,15763743,

**JSR223 PreProcessor**

```
def requiredOutput = new StringBuilder()
1.upto(vars.get('propertycount') as int, {
     requiredOutput.append(vars.get('propertyid' + it))
     requiredOutput
    requiredOutput.append(',')
    vars.put("outputString",requiredOutput.toString());

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seem to be constructing a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) therefore it makes more sense to consider using Groovy's [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) instead of doing manual string concatenation:

```
def outputString = []

1.upto(vars.get('PropertyCount') as int, {
    outputString.add(vars.get("propertyid$it"))
})

vars.put('outputString', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(outputString).toPrettyString())
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. This worked beautifully.